# How do I automate downloading a zipped file from a website

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate the download of zipped files from a website that do not have unique URL addresses. the data is in link below under related download on the right.  I do not have any experience with python or any script so I will need a tool that can be used by a novice.  I would also know if the automation can include the unzipping of the files.

I would appreciate any assistance/ advise.

http://phmsa.dot.gov/pipeline/library/data-stats/distribution-transmission-and-gathering-lng-and-liquid-annual-data

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You should improve your answer, show some efforts, and provide more details. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The type of question asking for software recommendations is not adequate here. However, you could try and see if [Flashget](http://www.flashget.com/) serves your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) as your starting place. I would write a script using that that will run once a day and check the zip file links for new ones.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/pipeline/library/data-stats/distribution-transmission-and-gathering-lng-and-liquid-annual-data'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
all_links = [link.get('href') for link in all_hrefs]
zip_files = [dl for dl in all_links if dl and '.zip' in dl]
```

This will get you a list of all the zip files (assuming the extension is always in lower case) on that main landing page. I would just save this information into a SQLite database or even just a plain text file that has each zip file on a single line. Then when you run the script, it would grab the links using the code above, open the database (or text file) and compare to see if there's anything new in there.

If it finds a new link, then you can download it using the wonderful [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. You would need something like this:

```
import os
import requests

root = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/'
download_folder = '/path/to/download/zip/files/'

for zip_file in zip_files:
    full_url = root + zip_file
    r = requests.get(full_url)
    zip_filename = os.path.basename(zip_file)
    dl_path = os.path.join(download_folder, zip_filename)
    with open(dl_path, 'wb') as z_file:
        z_file.write(r.content)
```

Here's a complete example that will just download all the zip files on the page every time you run it:

```
import os
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/pipeline/library/data-stats/distribution-transmission-and-gathering-lng-and-liquid-annual-data'
root = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
all_links = [link.get('href') for link in all_hrefs]
zip_files = [dl for dl in all_links if dl and '.zip' in dl]
download_folder = '/home/mdriscoll/Downloads/zip_files'

if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
    os.makedirs(download_folder)

for zip_file in zip_files:
    full_url = root + zip_file
    r = requests.get(full_url)
    zip_filename = os.path.basename(zip_file)
    dl_path = os.path.join(download_folder, zip_filename)
    with open(dl_path, 'wb') as z_file:
        z_file.write(r.content)
```

**Update #2** - Add Unzip capabilities:

```
import os
import requests
import zipfile

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/pipeline/library/data-stats/distribution-transmission-and-gathering-lng-and-liquid-annual-data'
root = 'http://phmsa.dot.gov/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
all_links = [link.get('href') for link in all_hrefs]
zip_files = [dl for dl in all_links if dl and '.zip' in dl]
download_folder = '/home/mdriscoll/Downloads/zip_files'

if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
    os.makedirs(download_folder)

tries = 0
for zip_file in zip_files:
    full_url = root + zip_file
    zip_filename = os.path.basename(zip_file)
    dl_path = os.path.join(download_folder, zip_filename)
    if os.path.exists(dl_path):
        # you have already downloaded this file, so skip it
        continue

    while tries < 3:
        r = requests.get(full_url)
        dl_path = os.path.join(download_folder, zip_filename)
        with open(dl_path, 'wb') as z_file:
            z_file.write(r.content)

        # unzip the file
        extract_dir = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(zip_file))[0]
        try:
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(dl_path)
            z.extractall(os.path.join(download_folder, extract_dir))
            break
        except zipfile.BadZipfile:
            # the file didn't download correctly, so try again
            # this is also a good place to log the error
            pass
        tries += 1
```

I noticed in my tests that occasionally the file wouldn't download correctly and I would get a `BadZipFile` error, so I added some code that will try 3 times before going on to the next file to download.

Comment: OK, I was able to download and install Python on my computer as well as “requests” and “BeautifulSoup”.  Since I am a novice with Python, I installed “PyCharm Edu” to run the code.  I tried running both scripts using PhyCharmEdu and I did not get anything back.  I was able to find the URL for the zip files (see below).  Could you show me how to get the file to download automatically?  Also, is it possible to unzip the file automatically via a script? http://www.phmsa.dot.gov/staticfiles/PHMSA/DownloadableFiles/Pipeline2data/annual_hazardous_liquid_2010_present.zip

Comment: I added a full example that downloads the all the zip files, but doesn't do any checking to see if you've already downloaded it. That should be easy to add. Python has a `zipfile` module that should work for unzipping them - https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Comment: Mike,  Thanks for the script.  It works perfectly.  I will take a look at the document to unzip files.

Comment: Updated one more time with a zipfile example

Comment: Mike - That is fantastic!  It works perfectly.  Thanks for all your help.